# Send Email by WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, winforms, smtp

I have developed on Windows Application. Now i need to send an email (attachment feature included) by Web Service. How can i do that?

Also i need to notify the email before 'n' days. ('n' days is a feature controlled by user)

Let me know if any comment.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you started attempting to do this yourself? What do you have so far?

Comment: I searched for the same but was not so successful :-(

Comment: Why do you need a webservice to achieve this? do you already use one?

Comment: No i dont have web service created.Its needed so that SMTP Credentials are not required to passed statically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public bool Send(string toAddress, string subject, string body, bool isHtml, List<string> files)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();

        mailMsg.To = toAddress;
        mailMsg.Headers.Add("From", string.Format("{0} <{1}>", senderName, senderAddress));
        mailMsg.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver"] = server;
        mailMsg.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport"] = port;
        mailMsg.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing"] = 2;

        if (enableAuth)
        {
            mailMsg.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate"] = 1;
            mailMsg.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername"] = userName;
            mailMsg.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword"] = password;
        }

        if (enableSsl)
        {
            mailMsg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl", "true");
        }

        if (isHtml)
        {
            mailMsg.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;
        }

        mailMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        mailMsg.Subject = subject;
        mailMsg.Body = body;

        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            mailMsg.Attachments.Add(new MailAttachment(files[i]));
        }
        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = server;
        SmtpMail.Send(mailMsg);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.errorMsg = ex.Message;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that you must use System.Web.Mail for this cod to work.

Comment: Hey thanks for the code.. But can i know how to do that in Web Service and access the same in WinForm Application

Comment: Well first of all you have to develop your Web Service and create 2 web methods. A method to upload your files to a tmp folder on the machine that hosts the web service. 2ed you need to call "Send" function with the list of file already uploaded (with the root of the tmp folder from the server).

Comment: thanks @stefan: Let me try this at my end and will comment if any hurdle..!