# Send email from webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, email, sendmail

I have a method to send mails from c#:

```
public static void SendEmailWebService(string asunto, string body, string to)
{
    try
    { // takes config from web.config
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage
        {
            From = new MailAddress(@"no-reply@site.com", @"Notificacion"),
            To = { new MailAddress(to) },
            Subject = asunto,
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            Body = body,
            HeadersEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
            SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
            BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        };
        Smtp.Send(mm);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Error
    }
}
```

If i call this method normaly, it works, but if i call it from a webservice then it fails.

In the cathc, the exception is:

> This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a
>   non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or
>   contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is
>   defined for this server.

I don't see why it's not worikng when I call it from the webservice.

Comment: Refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142654/send-email-by-webservice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is saying your mail server requires authentication. While there are many ways to achieve this, you can create a new `NetworkCredential` object and supply that to your mailmessage named parameters:

```
public static void SendEmailWebService(string asunto, string body, string to)
{
    try
    { // takes config from web.config
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage
        {
            From = new MailAddress(@"no-reply@site.com", @"Notificacion"),
            To = { new MailAddress(to) },
            Subject = asunto,
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            Body = body,
            HeadersEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
            SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
            BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password")
        };
        Smtp.Send(mm);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Error
    }
}
```

If you don't want to add the `NetworkCredential` to your source code you can also configure it from the web.config file

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp>
      <network host="" port="" userName="" password=""/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Correct. Does not matter if you use a webservice or a winforms application - it is all about how the email service is being hosted and what it requires for authentication.

Comment: You where right, i had the settings in the webconfig, but, for some reason It stoped working and I thought it did not work for the web service, thanks.